# Can you form alliances between the main story factions?

Tags: fallout-4

I have been playing the main story, and I believe I am approaching the point where I must chose between the factions. Is there a way to ally any of the factions, and if so, which? What faction will I have to join to create said alliance?

Comment: From what I have seen (in the quest guide book thing) No... Which is disappointing.. The only solutions the factions have to each other appears to be wiping each other out.

Comment: Ah. That's unfortunate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Minutemen**

If you finish the game with one of the other three factions, you can still be allied with the minutemen. It's probably not as formal of an alliance as you're hoping for. If you specifically support the Minutemen, then you'll be 
at war with the Institute, and potentially the other factions as well.

**Other Factions**

The other factions have deep-seated philosophical differences that prevent any kind of accord among them:

- The Institute believes that their science, and their synths in particular, are the future of mankind. The Brotherhood of Steel believes that no one else can be trusted with advanced technology.
- The Institute believes that synths are tools to be used as they see fit. The Railroad believes that synths are sentient beings with the same rights as humans.
- The Railroad wants to help synths to establish normal lives as peers among humans. The Brotherhood believes that synths are abominations of science that must be destroyed before they result in humanity's extinction.

This means that supporting any of these factions results in the destruction of the other two.

Comment: Are the minutemen not one of the main storyline factions?

Comment: @Sparrowetheguy I'm not sure how to answer that. Does that edit make things clearer?

Comment: Yes. I was wondering if you could beat the game by only allying with the minutemen and no one else.

Comment: @Sparrowetheguy yes its possible.  Its possible to beat the game with the minutemen without ever having made the BoS or Railroad hostile

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is an order in which you can do quests so the minutemen brotherhood and the railroad all make it out alive. There also happy about the end. I have a list of the quest order that i will be adding when i find it. If you go to youtube and look up, fallout 4 best ending, it well tell you how to make all three factions get along.

Answer (score 1):

No, sadly there is no way to make an alliance.

- If you side with the Brotherhood then you must destroy the Railroad
  and the Institute
- If you side with the institute then you must
  destroy the Railroad and the Brotherhood
- If you side with the
  Railroad you must destroy the Institute. You will also have to become enemies with the brotherhood.

Build the teleporter thing with the Minutemen to have more freedom with choices in the endgame but you must still decide who to wipe out.

Answer (score 0):

If you play as the brotherhood of steel become a paladin and then talk to the railroad you can ally them but in the end you still destroy the institute

Comment: Pretty sure you don't officially ally with the Railroad if you go down this path.  They are one of the factions the Brotherhood destroys since they are effectively in their way.  See the accepted answer.

Comment: @TimmyJim is right. You have to choose between BoS, Railroad, or Institute. Three choices, only one will survive.